# How to send data via telnet?

Tags: android, telnet

I would use telnet to send a simple string to an active service that is installed on Android emulator. Obviously this service has been developed by me, then, if required, I can also modify it.

How to send a string to my `Service` via telnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better question is how do you receive this string of data?
As Depado already has answered, if you have socket server which listens on android emulator side, for example, tcp server on localhost (192.168.1.10) and specific port (say 8000) then you can try to telnet:

```
telnet 192.168.1.10 8000
```

And 192.168.1.10 for example should be network IP address which is binded to android emulator, but I'm not sure how this part is done.

**Update**
As stated here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html :

> If you want to access services running on your development machine's loopback interface (a.k.a. 127.0.0.1 on your machine), you should use the special address 10.0.2.2 instead.

Also read section: *Emulator Networking*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Once a server socket is listening on port 8000, how can I connect with it? I tried entering the command `telnet localhost 8000`, but it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Connect to your service via telnet and then type what you want, then type enter and it will send a string to the listener of your application. (That's how telnet works in my head, but maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: Ok, but how do I connect telnet to my service? Or how do I change my service to make it so that it can connect to telnet and receive data from it?

Comment: Your application acts like a server right ? So it has an address and a port no ? If you created a service there must be a place where you defined all these things. Then just `telnet youripaddress:yourport`... Or I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Currently my `Service` can receive intents from other Android applications: the use of sockets is certainly an alternative, but I thought there was something simpler and faster to develop...

Comment: Then I can't help you, it seems that your problem is much complicated than what I thought. Sorry about that useless answer ^^

Comment: Socket programing isn't that hard so :)

Comment: I don't know how it works on an Android device. In C/C++ and Java sockets are quite easy but there must be some special things with Android that I don't know.

Comment: I have no problem about java sockets, so if there are no alternative solutions, I will use the sockets!